# Jquery get html Attr in youtube iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube, attr

How can i read with jquery an attr in YouTube iframe?

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" width="1024" height="576" frameborder="0" wmode="Opaque" allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.youtube.com/idvideo" type="text/html">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="de" data-cast-api-enabled="true" dir="ltr">
    .....
    .....
</iframe>
```

I need to know if is data-cast-api-enabled.

i have tried:

```
var iFrameDOM = $("iframe#ytplayer").contents();
var dataAttr = iFrameDOM.find("html").attr('data-cast-api-enabled');
alert('dataAttr')
```

But it does not work. I think this is a cross domain problem...

Comment: Similar question asked:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe